# PostgreSQL - How to get empty (null) records from the same table?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to get data from my table, including empty rows. For instance: I want to know, if there was some activity during last 30 minutes. If there was something, then I can get data and it works, but how to include those records without any activity? All my data are in the same table.

Thanks!

```
    ╔═════╦═════════════════════╦══════╗
    ║ SRV ║        DATE         ║ FLAG ║
    ╠═════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
    ║   1 ║ 2013-01-01 08:10:12 ║    4 ║
    ║   1 ║ 2013-01-01 08:11:24 ║    4 ║
    ║   1 ║ 2013-01-01 08:12:01 ║    5 ║
    ║   1 ║ 2013-01-01 08:12:14 ║    5 ║
    ║   2 ║ 2013-01-01 08:20:44 ║    4 ║
    ║   2 ║ 2013-01-01 08:23:11 ║    5 ║
    ║   1 ║ 2013-01-01 08:24:09 ║    4 ║
    ║   1 ║ 2013-01-01 08:28:54 ║    5 ║
    ║   1 ║ 2013-01-01 08:30:01 ║    4 ║
    ║   3 ║ 2013-01-01 08:32:31 ║    4 ║
    ║   3 ║ 2013-01-01 08:32:45 ║    4 ║
    ║   1 ║ 2013-01-01 08:35:21 ║    4 ║
    ╚═════╩═════════════════════╩══════╝
```

I want to get number of flags with status 4, in last 10 minutes in that case, grouped by SRV. When there was no flag 4 in specified time period, there should be record with SRV and NULL value. In this case, my query should return:

```
╔═════╦═══════╦══╗
║ SRV ║ COUNT ║  ║
╠═════╬═══════╬══╣
║   1 ║ 2     ║  ║
║   2 ║ NULL  ║  ║
║   3 ║ 2     ║  ║
╚═════╩═══════╩══╝
```

I was able to count existing flags using:

```
select srv, count(*)
from table1
where flag=4 and date >= now() - interval '10m'
group by svr
order by 1
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of you table, an example of the data and result, and the queries you already tried to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with SUM, this will return 0

```
select srv, SUM( CASE WHEN flag=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
from table1
where date >= now() - interval '10m'
group by svr
order by 1
```

If you really want NULL, then replace 0 with NULL:

```
select srv, 
       CASE SUM( CASE WHEN flag=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
            WHEN 0 THEN NULL
            ELSE SUM( CASE WHEN flag=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
       END
from table1
where date >= now() - interval '10m'now() - interval '10m'
group by svr
order by 1
```

---

In case there are no records with some SRV value in last 30 minutes, then the above queries don't list this SRV.
To correct this, you can use this query:

```
select srv, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN flag=4 AND date >= (now() - interval '10m')
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
from table1
group by srv
order by 1
```

but this query will always read the whole table, so may be ineficcient.

The below version reads all SRV values (if there is an index on SRV column, this operation should be fast), and perform the aggregation only on a subset of the table (last 30 minutes), therefore may be faster than the previous one:

```
SELECT q1.srv, q2.cnt
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT srv
   FROM table1
) q1
LEFT JOIN (
  select srv, count( * ) as cnt
  from table1
  where flag=4 AND date >= now() - interval '10m'
  group by svr
) q2
ON q1.srv = q2.srv
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :( I'm getting the same result as I would use count(*).

Comment: @user3091257 I am sorry, there were mistakes in queries. I corrected them, and added some new queries.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was supposed to achieve :) Works brilliant. I was thinking about using "join" but I'm a newbie to SQL. I can understand how to join two different tables, but I didn't know that You can join table to itself. Also, outer join is something that I need to learn, because it is a little complicated for me (for now).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this really simply - first, I would use some table with all possible values of `srv` (I used array, in order to keep it simple) and then just count all flags for that `srv` value:

```
SELECT
    s.x, CASE WHEN s.num = 0 THEN NULL ELSE s.num END
FROM (
    SELECT x, (
        SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM table1
        WHERE flag = 4 AND date >= NOW() - INTERVAL '10m' AND srv = x
    ) AS num
    FROM
        UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 2, 3]) AS x
    ORDER by x) AS s;
```

This returns:

```
 x | num 
---+-----
 1 |   2
 2 |    
 3 |   2
(3 rows)
```

If you have `srv` values in some table, just replace `UNNEST(ARRAY[..])` with
this table's name.